# How to prove this matrix is idempotent and that it obeys a telescoping identity

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices

Let $P_k$ be the size $k$ leading principal submatrix of the real-valued $N \times N$, invertible matrix $M$, and let $Q_k$ be the size $N$ matrix having $P_k^{-1}$ in the top left corner, and zeroes elsewhere.

Finally, define $S_k=M Q_k$.

For $j, k\in \{1,2, ... N\}$, how can we prove that:

1. $S_k$ is idempotent,
2. $S_j S_k = S_{{\rm min}[j,k]}$.

Comment: $S_k$ is the projection onto the span of the vectors $Me_1, Me_2, \ldots, Me_k$ along the span of the vectors $e_{k+1}, e_{k+2}, \ldots, e_N$.

Comment: This deals with part 1. Part 2 is actually false for $N = 3$, $j = 1$ and $k = 2$. (The three matrices $S_1S_2$, $S_2S_1$ and $S_1$ are all distinct.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. For the specific case you mention I get $S_1=S_2S_1=S_1S_2=\begin{bmatrix}   
1 & 0 & 0 \\
m_{2,1}/m_{1,1} & 0 & 0 \\
m_{3,1}/m_{1,1} & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Oops, I think I derped up my computations.

Comment: Okay, let me suggest a stupid proof. Do the case of $N = 3$, $j = 1$ and $k = 2$, without assuming the commutativity of the matrix entries. (Yes, it's true -- I've just checked it.) That argument will then work in the general case, by re-interpreting the matrices as block matrices.